# Tab delimeter to comma delimeter transfer trouble

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text-files

I have a question about printing data from a text file in a for loop with Python. Whenever I try to run this program that it says "could not convert string to float: KAAA" (KAAA is a string element in element[2]). I am trying to transfer the data from a text file with tab delimiters to a text file with comma delimiters. for some reason, this program works fine if I take away the third column of strings, but doesn't when I add it back in. Is there a way that I could get it so all three columns transfer into a text file with commas separating them? Here is a sample line from the data. "40.15869904  -89.33499908    KAAA."

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','mr_anderson')]


keywords = map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
keywords = ["k"+a+b+c for a,b,c in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]

start_time = time.time()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

try:
    a = 1
    b = 1
    List=[""]
    data = np.loadtxt("airportcodelatlonidentonlyk.txt")
    text_file_latlonair = open("latlontext.txt","a")
    for element in data:
        lat = str(element[0])
        lon = str(element[1])
        ident = str(element[2])
        text_file_latlonair.write(str(lat)+','+str(lon)+','+str(ident))
    text_file = open("nws_contourcurrenttemp_datatwo.txt","a")
    for i in range (1,50):
        i=1
        i+=1
        a+=1
        b+=1
        keywargs = str(keywords[a]).upper()
        argument = 'http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/'+keywargs+'.rss'
        page = 'http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KBED.rss'
        sourceCode = opener.open(page).read()
        #print(sourceCode)
        req = Request(argument)


        try:
            page_open = urlopen(req)
        except:
            None

        else:

            c=1
            c+=1
            sourceCode = opener.open(argument).read()
            KBEDforecastraw = re.findall(r'and\s\d{1,2}\s\w.*?',str(sourceCode))
            windraw = re.findall(r'at\s\d{1,2}\.\d{0,1}.*?',str(sourceCode))
            pressureraw = re.findall(r'The pressure is\s\d{1,4}\.\d{0,1}\s\w\w.*?',str(sourceCode))
            humidraw = re.findall(r'the humidity is\s\d{1,2}\%.*?',str(sourceCode))

            try:
                KBEDtemp = KBEDforecastraw[0]
                KBED = str(KBEDtemp).strip("[and F]")
                #text_file.write(KBEDtemp)

            except:
                None
            else:
                text_file.write(KBED+'\n')
                #print(KBED)
                #print(str(KBEDforecastraw)+' '+keywargs+str(windraw)+str(pressureraw)+str(humidraw))








except Exception, e:
    print(str(e))



print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from your `np` variable you're using `numpy` which assumes that data passed into `load` is float type. It looks like your code assumes that everything is a string so just pass in the `str` datatype.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html